# Python: return function variables and assign to new variables

Tags: python, function, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a function that returns a dict of pandas dataframes.  The dict has a key and the key for each dataframe is its corresponding name.

```
def fun(inputs):
x = calculations
y = calculations
z = calculations, etc.
return: {'name1':x,'name2':y,'name3':z}
```

I would like to use some of these dataframes as variables elsewhere in my code. To do this, I currently do the following:

```
x = fun()
var1 = x['name1']
var2 = x['name2']
var3 = x['name3']
```

and so on.  I would like to do this more efficiently (fewer lines of code).  In my mind, I should be able to do something like this:

```
[var1,var2,var3]   = fun()
```

But this just assigns each name to each variable as a string.  Can this be done?  or should my function output be setup differently?

Comment: Why not just *use the dictionary*?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Reaching for the `['']` keys all the time is awkward, it makes your statements bulkier, and your IDE won't be as helpful with dict entries as with variables.

Comment: Then don't use a dictionary, and return a tuple and use tuple unpacking assignment.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: But then you have to remember which slots you put everything in, and you're stuck with whatever order you pick. namedtuples can help, but they still have issues.

Comment: ... OK, I've never found it too difficult to keep it all organized, especially if you use namedtuples. But regardless, look at the functionality the OP is imagining utilizing this: `[var1,var2,var3]   = fun()` how does this in any way take advantage of the nice properties of dictionaries we all know and love?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)***

- `import` the `namedtuple` function from `collections`
- Use it to create a new `class` that you can then use to instantiate new class members
- Accessing the named elements now utilizes the dot notation.

---

```
from collections import namedtuple

mydfs = namedtuple('MyDFs', ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'])

def fun(inputs):
    x = calculations
    y = calculations
    z = calculations, etc.
    return mydfs(x, y, z)


x = fun(inputs)

x.name1
```

If you want, you can also unpack one of these:

```
var1, var2, var3 = x
```

***Old Answer***

Easiest way is to pass that dictionary to the `pd.Panel` constructor

```
pn = pd.Panel({'name1':x,'name2':y,'name3':z})
```

This is can now be thought of as a series of dataframes.  Each dataframe can be accessed via `pn['name1']` etc.

Comment: So... we access the dataframes exactly the same way we would have with the dict? It's not clear how this gets us anywhere.

Comment: @user2357112 `True`.  It's more convenient cohesive structure.  But access is identical.  I'll have to rethink it.

Comment: `pd.Panel` is also facing an oncoming depreciation, I recently learned.

Comment: @Mitch that stinks... But I guess I'll get over it.

Comment: @piRSquared Need to warm up to `xarray` integration! :)